# Excel freezes during execution of vba

Tags: vba, excel

This find and highlight vba is run when I click the button on a user form, even though it highlights the first instance, excel freezes and does not respond for a long time. Does not show any bug or such.

```
     Private Sub changebutton_tp_Click()
     Dim sheet As Worksheet
     Dim table_list_obj As ListObject
     Dim table_obj_row As ListRow
     Set sheet = Sheets("TermGUI")


    Dim rng As Range


    Set rng = sheet.Cells.Find(What:=TermPage.wordfound_tp.Value,_
LookIn:xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Term Not Found")
    ElseIf IsEmpty(rng) Then
        MsgBox ("Term Not Found")
    ElseIf rng = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Term Not Found")
    Else
        With sheet.UsedRange
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            Do Until rng Is Nothing
                sheet.Cells.Find(What:=TermPage.wordfound_tp.Value,_
               LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).Activate
                With Selection.Interior
                    .ColorIndex = 6
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                End With
            Loop
        End If
        End With
        Set rng = Nothing
        MsgBox ("Term Found and Highlighted")
    End If

End Sub
```

OK, I have identified the infinite loop, however what I want to do is to find all the terms that match the inquiry and highlight them. Without the loop it just does for one instance.

Comment: you could `Dim cll As Range` and then create a `For Each cll In "range you want to loop over"` loop

Comment: Is there some reason you avoided `For Each`? Your `Do Until` is basically performing the same thing...

Comment: I figured out in a simpler way using find and findnext. And no reason for avoiding for each. I am just new at VBA. Second day actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Do Until rng Is Nothing '// <~~ stop condition here will never be met
       sheet.Cells.Find(What:=TermPage.wordfound_tp.Value,_
       LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).Activate
        With Selection.Interior
            .ColorIndex = 6
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
Loop
```

---

The object `rng` never becomes `Nothing` during your loop - and so this code will loop infinitely.

Perhaps something like this would be better:

```
Do Until rng Is Nothing
        Set rng = Nothing
        Set rng = sheet.Cells.Find(What:=TermPage.wordfound_tp.Value,_
       LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            With rng.Interior
                .ColorIndex = 6
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            End With
        End If
        DoEvents '// <~~ IMPORTANT if you want to be able to break the loop manually.
    Loop
```

Comment: This ends the loop but I want to find all of the terms that match the user input and highlight all of them. Otherwise just for one term, I wasn't even using a loop in the first place

Comment: Then you need to look at using the `.FindNext()` method - but that isn't your question. A quick google will show you how to use it with examples

Comment: I have been trying to fix the code to highlight for last couple of hours but got me nowhere. Can you help me out? shared the edited code in the comment

Comment: Here's an example of what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806323/vba-findnext-issue

Answer (score 1):

### Resolution:

Because of this line:
`Do Until rng Is Nothing`

**It probably won't stop being** **`Nothing` any time soon.**

### Tip for future:

- Do try to debug line by line <kbd>F8</kbd> or
  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to find issues first.
- If you want to prevent code freezing when doing long code loops do add `DoEvents` at the end of each loop. This will allow you to break your code using <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub changebutton_tp_Click()
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim table_list_obj As ListObject
Dim table_obj_row As ListRow
Set sheet = Sheets("TermGUI")
Dim cll As Range

Dim rng As Range


Set rng = sheet.Cells.Find(What:=TermPage.wordfound_tp.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Term Not Found")
ElseIf IsEmpty(rng) Then
    MsgBox ("Term Not Found")
ElseIf rng = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Term Not Found")
Else
    With sheet.UsedRange
       For Each cll In Worksheets("TermGUI").Range("A1", "A100").Cells
            sheet.Cells.Find(What:=TermPage.wordfound_tp.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).Activate
            With Selection.Interior
                .ColorIndex = 6
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            End With
        Next
    DoEvents
    End With
    MsgBox ("Term Found and Highlighted")
End If

End Sub
```